# References per chapter

Tags: bibliographies

I've been trying to go through previous questions and found some answers, however, I cannot find my mistake. I'm trying to have a bibliography after each chapter in my thesis. The current of the main file is:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[semicolon,round,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}  
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
        \chapter{Introduction}}
        \import{./5_Introduction/}{Introduction.tex}
        \graphicspath{{./5_Introduction/Images/}}
\end{document}
```

Within the Introduction part I call

```latex
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Int-References}
```

With the Int-references being a .bib file saved via JabRef.

The program I'm using is Texmaker.

I presume I'm doing something wrong in calling the .aux to generate the references when executing the main file. I just don't my mistake.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Dis you run bibtex for each resulting bibliography for your several chapters. To be clear: if you have five chapters you need five separate bibtex runs!

Comment: Dear Mensch, I think I did. But I might have discovered my problem. Looking back at it tell the usepackage chapterbib works with \include while I'm using \import. I'm going to give that a try now.

Comment: Ok that solved the problem... but thank you for the quick response.

Comment: The combination of `\import` and `\include` is `\includefrom`.

Answer (score 2):

You must start each chapter with `\bibliographystyle{...}` and end with `\bibliography{...}`. In my lecture notes each chapter is a separate file, `\include{...}` pulls them into the main file.

Comment: Dear Vonbrand, 

thank you for the quick reply. In my experience the location of \bibliographystyle{..} does not matter. However, I did use \import over \include, which caused the problem

Comment: Switch to `\includefrom`. You really do need `\bibliographystyle` in each chapter file, so when you run bibtex on that portion the style is selected.